# Manipulate a part of variable while keeping the original intact

Tags: python, list, max, substitution

What would be the cleanest way to manipulate / use / remove part of a variable whilst keeping the original variable intact.

Lets say I wanted the value in the following list that corresponds to the highest numerical value

So for example:

```
max([1, 2, '3a', '10b'])
```

should be evaluated as

```
max([1, 2, 3, 10])
```

and the value `'10b'` should be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended approach using `re.search()` function:

```
import re

max_item = max([1, 2, '3abc', '10bc'], key=lambda n: int(re.search(r'\d+', str(n)).group(0)))
print(max_item)
```

The output:

```
10bc
```

Answer (score 6):

The `max` function accepts a `key` argument, which is used to calculate the value which will be used for the comparison. E.g.:

```
max([1, 2, '3a', '10b'], key=lambda x: x if isinstance(x, int) else int(x[:-1]))
```

Fill in your own conversion function for the `lambda` there.

Comment: Assumes only the last character is a letter, also assumes not `float`s (may or may not be correct assumptions for this particular case)

Comment: Hence the last sentence; I can only go on the little bit of information given here…

Comment: This is perfect, can work with the lambda function to fix it up.

Comment: @deceze Or you could take on the challenge of writing a more generic `lambda` function yourself. Anyway, the OP seems happy so I'll shut up